# Frequency weights for logistic regression in R

Tags: regression, logistic

I would like to fit a logistic regression model in R.  The data collection process results in an un-balanced amount of events and non-events.  I could re-sample from the data to re-create the original prevalance of the events, but I would rather use all the data.

The glm() function in R does not use weights as sampling weights, but uses weights as an integer number of trials. From the help page "when the elements of weights are positive integers w_i, that each response y_i is the mean of w_i unit-weight observations".  See also this question, [Case weighted logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14324/case-weighted-logistic-regression),  for more on smapling vs trial weights.

Is there an R package to compute a sampling weighted MLE, or what are other options?

Comment: What do you mean by "R does not use weights to modify the MLE"? If you use the options of `weights` for `glm` in R , then all the estimations will be adjusted taking into account the weights you specify.

Comment: re-worded that to make the subtle difference in type of weights more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Sampling weights in logistic regression are implemented by `svyglm` from the `survey` package (setting the weights is done by using `svydesign` to define a design object, which `svyglm` takes as an argument)